# Копирование в буфер с помощью кнопки

Tags: flash, wordpress, javascript

Хочу к заголовку сделать кнопочку "Скопировать", которая копирует в буфер URL статьи.
Подскажите, как такое сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.location
```

содержит все необходимое.

```
document.location.hostname
```

вернет базовый URL

```
document.location.href
```

скорее всего вернет то, что вам необходимо если я правильно понял.

```
document.location.pathname
```

вернет все кроме базового URL.

Для IE вот такое должно сработать, для записи в буфер

```
clipboardData.setData('text', s);
```